# Access Lages child and disable it in CSS

Tags: html, css, parent-child

I have something like this:

```
<label for="billing:postcode" class="required"><em>*</em>Zip/Postal Code</label>
```

Now I want to disable `<em>` from displaying (using `display: none`) directly from the CSS. How Can I accomplish that?

Comment: Whoever it is, I don't think we should be accessing the child without his, or her, approval...

Answer (score 2):

you may write

```
label em { display: none }
```

but this would be applied to all `em` elements for all `label`, so you could write a more specific selector like

```
label[for^="billing"] em
```

or also

```
label.required em
```

The choice of what selector or which specificity you should use it depends on your markup

Answer (score 2):

you can use one of the following.

```
em
{
    display: none;
}

.required em
{
    display: none;
}

label em
{
    display: none;
}

[for^="billing"] em
{
    display: none;
}
```

But I would go with:

```
<label for="billing:postcode" class="required"><em class="disabled">*</em>Zip/Postal Code</label>

.disabled
{
    display: none;
}
```